# TFS 2013 migration to visual studio online with Opshub team foundation server user list

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-migration, opshub

I am attempting to migrate TFS 2013 team project to visual studio online using OpsHub visual studio online migration utility.  When I get to the step where I have to select the team foundation server users to migrate it appears that my companies entire active directory is being loaded (over 38,000 users!). I really only want to migrate about 25 users, but it is telling me that I must migrate every users.  As a note, when I create a new work item in TFS 2013, only 25 users are displayed in the drop down.

I am sure that there is some group that needs to be configured for TFS but I am not sure what exactly I need to do to get this list to only include the few people I need to migrate.

Edit:

I noticed in my DefaultCollection Windows Group section that we have a Dev-Contributors group with the exact people I want, but there is also a domain user group that contains my companies entire active directory. I am positive that dev-contributors is the only group we really need, is it advisable to somehow remove the domain users group?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utility loads all the valid users assigned to the collection group membership. This loads all the valid users in all the projects of that collection. Can you check your valid user group?, this might have clubbed all the users from your domain user group as you have already mentioned. As a workaround you can skip this user list from group membership of collection if it is not really used inside that collection, or you can remove this group during the migration configuration time.

You can also map multiple users from source side to one single user on target side, here you can select all unwanted users to any of the target user.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I will work with my network admin to make sure the proper configuration is applied to our groups.